# Plotting a polarization-electric field curve (hysteresis) with every data needed

Tags: matlab

I want to plot a hysteresis curve in MATLAB illustrating the polarization-electric field of a device. I basically have the electric field (incoming voltage pulse divided with the distance between the two plates in a plate capacitor. I also have the current vs time. To get the polarization I need firstly the charge `Q(t)` by integrating the current over time. The problem is the data includes NaN-values and I need to get rid of this whilst the current-vector and time-vector is still the same size. Secondly, the charge `Q(t)` should be divided with the area of the plates, and there I should have it. But I do not know:

1) How to get rid of the `NaN` values whilst still having the same size of the vectors

2) An appropriate function that integrates current over time so I get the charge `Q(t)`. Note it is dependent on `t` and should yield an answer with a vector corresponding the size of the integrating vectors.

Answer (score 0):

**0)** If you edit your question to include a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we'd be able to help better. Briefly:

**1)** You'll need to interpolate the values. Something like this ought to work for simple cases:

```
close all; clear; clc;

% Make some aritficial data
N = 1e2; % number of data points
x = linspace(0,1,N);
y = sin(2*pi*x) + 0.1*randn(1,N);
y([randsample(1:N,30)]) = NaN; % Introduce NaNs

% Fix bad values
bad = isnan(y);
yi = interp1(x(~bad),y(~bad),x,'linear');

% Plot
plot(x,yi,'.-',x,y,'o');
legend('Interpolated data','Corrupted data')
grid on; box on; axis square;
```

Aside: Be aware that the problem of interpolation becomes much more tricky when you work with multidimensional and/or unevenly sampled data. Have a look, for example, at [image inpainting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43020219/2531987) to see how this could be done for 2D, evenly sampled data.

**2)** Matlab's [`trapz`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html) takes the x-axis as an optional argument and performs the trapezoidal integration of the input signal. If what you want is, instead, a cumulative trapezoid integral, use the function [`cumtrapz`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumtrapz.html). You'll most likely not need anything more complicated than these two.